# COGNOS 8 Bi value prompt

Tags: reporting, cognos

Currently I have a value prompt added to my report (with UI selected as List-Box) and the date item used is name 'YEAR'. Now when I run the report the values in the value prompt are seen as below:

### YEAR

**2004**

**2005**

**2006**

What I want to do is get rid of the year tag that is present in the output of the value prompt box, more clearly the output in the value prompt box should be as below:

**2004**

**2005**

**2006**

Can someone let me know how that can be achieved?

Comment: Ok, I removed the DAMN CAPITALS. Now you can remove the downvotes and start answering :)

Comment: What's wrong with this guy's CAPS LOCK key? http://webpages.charter.net/krumsick/ <- Just get rid of it!

Comment: SERIOUSLY, Rahul - STOP TYPING EVERYTHING IN ALL UPPERCASE. This is considered SCREAMING at people and its considered rude behavior. You'll have more luck getting good answers if you use normal lower- and uppercase as everyone else does

Comment: Sorry guys was using this site from a Remote desktop which for some reason was not letting me type in lower case regardless of my caps lock being on or not. i even tried using shift key but it did not work. now i ahve logged on using my desktop. i am sorry if it is hurting seems like a rude behaviour. now request some answers. thanks martinho correcting the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hi guys i kinda figured out how this can be done. its just two lines of script which does the job. Since  i din get any answer i thought not many people know about this so i am posting it here.

Lets say i name my List Box 'promptYear'

Then the following piece of code put in an HTML item does the job.

```
<script> document.formWarpRequest._oLstChoicespromptYear.remove(0); document.formWarpRequest._oLstChoicespromptYear.remove(0); </script>
```